# How to center the views using constraint chains in android

Tags: android

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/headerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/headerTextView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to align `TextView` and `Button` vertically centered. I am using constraint chains property but it is not working.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: try this : Give textview left and right constraint to button and remove gravity.